# Listing Group Memberships for Each Direct Report

Tags: powershell

This script helps identify direct reports up to a manager based on user input. What I am trying to accomplish is When the user provides a manager account (i.e. mburkhart) it will return all employees and their group memberships.

For example, when mburkhart is entered, the expected return will be "John Smith and all his group memberships." Then the next line will be "Sally Jones and all her group memberships."

Looking for some help automating this process.

```
Write-Host . LIST DIRECT REPORTS . -ForegroundColor white -BackgroundColor red
$Manager = Read-Host [ Enter Manager User Name ]
Write-Host ... These are Direct Reports to $Manager -ForegroundColor yellow
Get-ADUser -Identity $Manager -Properties directreports | select-object -ExpandProperty DirectReports
```

Comment: I don't have the AD tools installed on my personal laptop, but if you can include the outputs of Get-ADUser, and the last line of your code, I could write you a solution.

Comment: The code posted is all I have right now. The output from running that include: CN=John Smith,OU=Desktop Admins,OU=Users,DC=xyz,DC=local
,,,,,CN=Sally Jones,OU=Desktop Admins,OU=Users,DC=xyz,DC=local
,,,,,CN=Andy Bird,OU=Desktop Admins,OU=Users,DC=xyz,DC=local

Comment: How would you like the output to be formatted? You will have one user (a manager) with multiple direct reports. Each of those direct reports will be members of many groups. That's multiple arrays that all need to be associated with each other.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Using this [microsoft page as reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps), here's my approach.

### Code

```bsh
$Manager = 'mburkhart'
Get-ADUser -Identity $Manager -Properties directreports | % {
    $Name = $_.Name
    $Memberships = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_ | % name
    [PsCustomObject]@{Name = $Name; Memberships = $Memberships}
}
```

This will be printed as a table that kinda resembles:
[image]

Comment: Typically the command would be something like this for any organization... get-adprincipalgroupmembership username | select name ...... but that is not successful with your updates.

Comment: Try the new update @mburkhart, I am going based on what I can find online, but this should be it based on what you gave me

Comment: Also what version of PowerShell are you running?

Answer (score 0):

If we are staying with your code format and console coloring scheme, you can do the following:

```
Write-Host . LIST DIRECT REPORTS . -ForegroundColor white -BackgroundColor red
$Manager = Read-Host [ Enter Manager User Name ]

$directReports = Get-ADUser -Identity $Manager -Properties directreports | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports
$output = $directReports | Select-Object @{n='DirectReports';e={($_ -split 'CN=|,OU=|,DC=')[1]}},@{n='Groups';e={Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name}}
Write-Host ... These are Direct Reports to $Manager -ForegroundColor yellow
$output.DirectReports
$output | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host ... These are the groups for $($_.DirectReports) -ForegroundColor Green
    $_.Groups
}
```

Comment: that works pretty good. Now if I wanted to export that, wouldn't it be something like $directReports | export-csv -Path C:\Audit\TestFile.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Thought that would work, but I just get a bunch of numbers

Comment: If you want it to go to CSV instead, you need to remove the `-ExpandProperty` parameter from `$directReports` assignment. That will have an effect on the rest of the code. The `$output` assignment would need to replace `$_` with `$_.DirectReports`.

Comment: `$directReports = Get-ADUser -Identity $Manager -Properties directreports | Select-Object DirectReports`

Comment: `$output = $directReports | Select-Object @{n='DirectReports';e={($_ -split 'CN=|,OU=|,DC=')[1]}},@{n='Groups';e={Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.DirectReports | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name}}`

Comment: Not providing me the expected output... Did I make the change in the wrong place?

Comment: The `$_ -split` part needs to be `$_.DirectReports -split`.